# PHP Rename all files in a directory with random names

Tags: php, image, rename

I have a directory of 5000 images on my website. What could I do in PHP to rename all of the images in the directory with completely random names (e.g ri32rif293jf32f3f or whatever)?

I need to know this so I can randomly rename them all every couple months.

Comment: what have you tried? show what you've done already. This type of questions are not welcomed in the community.

Comment: Are you trying to rename the files for security?

Comment: I haven't really tried anything since I don't know how to do it. The only part I know is how to come up with a random name, that's why I didn't write any code.

Comment: Sounds like you just want to prevent hotlinking; have you [searched](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=php+image+hotlink+protection) for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function random($numchars,$digits,$small,$capital,$splchr)
{
$dig = "0123456789";

$sml = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

$spl = "!@#$%*";

$cap = "ABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

if($digits == 1)
{
    $str .= $dig;
}

if($small == 1)
{
    $str .= $sml;
}

if($capital == 1)
{
    $str .= $cap;
}

if($splchr == 1)
{
    $str .= $spl;
}

for($j=0; $j < $numchars; $j++)
{
    $randomized .= $str{ rand() % strlen($str) };
}

return $randomized;
}

    $source = "/source direcotry/";
    $destination = "/destination directory/";
    function getDirectory( $source, $destination, $level=0)
    {
    $count =1;

       $ignore = array( 'cgi-bin', '.', '..' );
       if($handle = opendir($source))
       { 
        //one by one reading a file
        while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) 
        {
           if( is_dir( "$source/$file" ) )
              if (!file_exists($destination.$file))
                 mkdir("$destination$file", 0700);
           if( !in_array( $file, $ignore ) )
           {
              if( is_dir( "$source/$file" ) )
              {
                getDirectory( "$source$file/", "$destination$file/", ($level+1));
              }
              else 
              { 
                  $rand = random(16,1,1,1,1);
                  $srcfile = file_get_contents($source.$file);
                  $extfile=substr($file, strrpos($file, "."));      
                  file_put_contents($destination.$rand.$extfile , $srcfile);
              }
           }
        }
        $total[$level] = $total + intval($count-1);
        echo "<br/><b> $destination  ---- ".intval($count-1)."</b><br/><br/>";
      }
      closedir($handle); 
    }
    //calling getDirectory function for repeat the for all sub folders.
    getDirectory( $source , $destination, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty straight forward:

1. You create yourself a function that can generate a random filename.
2. You obtain the list of files in that directory.
3. You create a second list with an entry per each file of the old list carrying the new name that has been generated with the function from 1.) and that does not exist in the list of 2.) and is not so far part of the list of 3.).
4. Rename the files of 2.) with their new names of 3.)

Done. Wrap all this into a function of it's own so you can easily call it every couple months.

Comment: Thanks, but I was thinking more of a method which just iterates through the directory, by I guess putting them all into an array at the beginning.

Comment: Yes, that is 2.) in the listing above.